Why is my M2 Mac not identifying libraries installed via brew?
I am losing my mind.
I am currently trying to get a start on a school project, of which I am already anxious of due to its scale and the small amount of time I have to get it done. So, the last thing I need is something like this stopping me in my tracks 
The library to be used is <nlohmann/json.hpp>, by which I have successfully installed through homebrew. The package itself can be found in opt/homebrew but for some reason I am still getting errors in CLion, with disheartening underlines telling me the library cannot be found.
I've spent the last hour seeking solutions to this - both specific and general, but many have either been attempted to no avail, or made no sense to me (a noob CS student) whatsoever (something about CMake??).
I'd really love to get this fixed. As I said, the respective files are installed in homebrew, but to my IDE and compiler they are not to be found. Is there a way I can simply drag and drop these files into where the others are? For example, I am using <curl/curl.h> also, which has given me no trouble. Can I put the files for <nlohmann/json.hpp> where curl is found and expect it to work?
I'm such a noob. Please help me.
I tried all other possible solutions found on Stack and Reddit - such as adding particular commands to my shell config file. Still, nothing is connecting.

How are you actually compiling and running your code? You put in your life story but no concrete code, build files or error messages.

What does your CMakeLists.txt file look like? it sounds like it's missing a line such as include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi guys, sorry for not providing adequate information for you to help me better. I am attempting to compile my code as normal (clang++ -std=C++11 -o etc.), but because the libraries cannot be found it of course, won't compile. I also cannot locate the CMakeLists.txt file. Sorry again, cannot stress how new this all is to me, from it being my first Stack post to writing a project of this scale.

If you're 'building by hand' it doesn't provide any mechanism for clion to determine include paths, etc. Effectively a CMakeLists.txt file allows you to describe what you're building and what you depend on in a structured manner, which leads to an easier process for building, etc, as well as allowing other tools to interrogate it for things such as include paths to remove the dread red squiggle.

By using a CMakeLists.txt file, you are able to specify things in a slightly better semantic view than hand-cranking clang++ commands to get things to build. This can also be read by an IDE to give you help in relation to building, completion, etc.
I created a very simple project, which in CLion automatically made a CMakeLists.txt file for building it, which is relatively short. I'll try to go through it line-by line, and mention my own change to the file, which will allow it to include the nlohman library, which is usable header-only (there is no library needed, which simplifies things significantly):
# declare the minimum version of cmake to use
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
# declare the name of the project
project(untitled)

# we're going to use C++17 standard for our code - you can replace
# this with 11, if you're going to use C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

# search for headers in /opt/homebrew/include
include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)

# when building the executable 'jsonreader'
# use the source from jsonreader.cpp. If we had a second
# file called jsonwriter.cpp we would add it here also.
# we would also include any local header files here.
add_executable(jsonreader jsonreader.cpp)

The Jetbrains website has a Quick CMake tutorial, which contains much of the detail here, as well as calling out specifics.
